# Where is the proper place for math jokes?

Tags: support

Is it permissible to post a joke related to math on some board or other on the StackExchange network, or is this sort of levity not permitted? (I thought I'd ask first so I wouldn't attempt something that wasn't allowed. And yes, the joke I have is clean.)

Comment: Plenty of jokes related to math have been posted here and on main. Some have even been intentional. Most of those have been in comments.

Comment: here of course. post em all. what do you mean by clean?

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/68/questions-about-math-jokes

Comment: It's not really levity that makes this inadmissible, it's that we're a Q&A site, not a discussion board.  Humor and happiness are not frowned on, but posts should remain on topic and conform to the format of the site.

Comment: By the way, there are math joke threads on MO [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist) and [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/38856/25494) and [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/46837/25494).

Comment: How is this a bad question? 5 down votes? Meta is supposed to be for support. The guy asked a genuine enough question.

Comment: @GeoffPointer negative votes on meta doesn't necessarily mean that the question is bad. I would interpret the downvotes here to mean that jokes in general are off-topic on math.stackexchange.

Comment: This tells me the way some people vote doesn't make sense at all. If the guy was suggesting that jokes be allowed and actively encouraged, then negative votes would make sense if jokes really were a bad idea on a site like this. But, this was a support question and he was asking for clarification on their appropriateness. The question highlights the issue and the comments/answers make it clear what the policy is. Negative votes on questions such as these are going to discourage others asking similar questions. Instead they'll make up their own minds and where will that lead?

Answer (score 8):

The main site and the meta site are ruled out, but it'd probably be welcome in chat!

Comment: Am I allowed to post a joke about casting out 9's as a comment on a question or answer related to computing a mod (remainder), or would this be seen as an attempt to get away with breaking the rules?

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink There's quite a bit of levity about the place in comments. If it's a rule, it's being broken often enough.